# SUSPECT in mdf files

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I run

```
ALTER DATABASE EMS102013 SET SINGLE_USER;

DBCC CHECKDB (EMS102013) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS
```

shows message

> Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Check terminated. A failure was
>   detected while collecting facts. Possibly tempdb out of space or a
>   system table is inconsistent. Check previous errors.

how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Well, the error message certainly lists a possibility that is easy to check: is the drive tempdb on out of space?

Comment: I'd also suggest you run CHECKDB against your system databases (master, msdb, model) and see if they show any error messages. As Aaron suggested, you should also check to see if tempdb is out of space, or if tempdb is not able to autogrow.

Comment: I think you have a damaged page in a critical system table, the only way you are going to recover from this is to restore from a clean backup. Hope this was helpful